# Providing layout resource for Nexus4/Nexus7 against NexusOne/NexusS

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to provide 2 different layouts for these 4 devices. I want Nexus4 (1280x720) and Nexus7(1024x600) use layoutA and NexusOne/NexusS (both 800x480) to use LayoutB.

I read the developer guide and still cannot figure out what kind of qualification I should specify to the different layout folders in "/res".

What's more, I even want the NexusOne/NexusS to use layoutA in portrait mode and layoutB in landscape mode.

In a summary, the threshold of the difference is the width and the density of the screen. I want to:

```
w>480dp use layoutA
w<480dp use layoutB
```

Can I achieve these goals at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the docs - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

For N4/N7 have the resource directories

```
layout-sw600/layoutA
```

For N1/NS have the resource directories

```
layout/layoutB
```

Taking into consideration landscape and horizontal layouts, have an additional directory for N1/NS alone.

N1/NS

```
layout-port/layoutA
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, your answer is closer to the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

It's wall written in the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). The folders you want are:

```
/res/layout-sw480         with layout A
/res/layout-land-sw480    with layout B
/res/layout-land-sw720    with tablet and nexus4 layout
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the gentlemen's answers above. I have tried many combinations of the qualifications and finally figured out the correct one:

```
/layout - small layout for short width as N1/NS-port, QVGA-port
/layout-w360dp - big layout for large screens N4/N7, and for landscape mode of N1/NS and QVGA
/layout-land - same as above
```

This works fine for me. The trick here is that QVGA is ldpi, N7 is mdpi, N1/NS is hdpi, N4/GN is xhdpi. I haven't tried it on a screen smaller than 320x480